# Meaning of the word 水戸黄門. Is there a hidden nuance?

Tags: meaning, translation, nuances, anime

I was re-watching Usagi Drop.
When the MC tries to unfold a plastic bag or something, his hands are not slippery enough to separate the plastic handle. After harassing him in a cute way, the little girl says:

> **あっ！　『水戸黄門』**

I paused and checked the English subs to see what I missed. It was translated as "Keep trying then"

This of course is not the literal translation, so I wanted to check if it carried some hidden meaning. Turns out **水戸黄門** is a Japanese TV show which used to run for quite a long time. Since every language has similar connections of events to scenes from popular dramas, I was wondering if someone could read between the lines and enlighten me

Comment: It seems he said 黙らっしゃい according to this [transcript](https://www.lingq.com/en/lesson/usagi-drop-episode-6-my-tree-3841646/). She probably responded to that.

Comment: Please read [this](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2189/5010), and next time please include the episode number and several sentences before this. It is totally impossible to reach the correct answer with only the information you wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the actual video (うさぎドロップ 第6話 わたしの木). The girl said "あっ、水戸黄門" simply because the guy just said 黙らっしゃい like 水戸黄門. For now, you have to know nothing about him other than that he is an old man in a samurai drama.

黙らっしゃい is one of the fixed ways to say "Shut up!", but it's uncommon and sounds old-fashioned. It's basically part of 老人語 today. If a middle-aged guy uses it like in this episode, it's probably a joke. Besides, the tone of his voice was oddly husky and theatrical, which may also be a reason she was reminded of 水戸黄門. Maybe they had seen the drama and the girl had learned 黙らっしゃい shortly before this scene.